# Refuse authentication if domain controller is down

Tags: active-directory

I would want a gpo to forbid authentication in case of breakdown of the controller of domain or rodc (read only domain controller)

If possible to make that with GPO :)

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the number of credentials cached by the host to 0 and you'll get this behavior.